# Print unsigned int in decimal base NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've following trouble. I need to write function which will print signed integers as unsigned to STDIO. So with '-1' function should write '18446744073709551615' cause it's 0b11111111111111111...1. My function can write only numbers from 0b000...0 to 0b0111...1. Can you tell me principles how should it works?

```
print_uint:
        mov     rax, 1  
        mov     rbx, 10 
        mov     r10, 0
.loop:  mul     rbx
        inc     r10
        cmp     rax, r9
        jb      .loop

.tg:    mov     rax, rdi
        add     r10, intbuf
        dec     r10
        mov rdi, r10
.div:
        cqo
        div rbx
        add byte[rdi], 30h
        add byte[rdi], dl
        dec rdi
        cmp rax, 0
        je .finish
        jmp .div
.finish:
        mov rdi, intbuf
        call print_string
        call purge_intbuf
        ret
```

Comment: Why `cqo`? That should answer your question.

Comment: Yea, it was my fault